# Google Cloud Run: interpreting CPU utilization metrics for concurrency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, concurrency, google-cloud-run

In GCR docs about concurrency, it's recommended to allow concurrent connections unless you anticipate that each request will max out the CPU/RAM (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency-1).

I'm having trouble interpreting the "metrics" graph (picture below).

Questions:

1. Does this mean that my requests are using about 20% of the CPU?  The graph says so, but the legend lists the red line as 95%:17%, which means nothing to me.
2. If yes (i.e. 20% CPU), does this mean I can safely increase concurrency to 4-5 (20% x 5 = 100%)?
3. If I increase the number of CPUs, will I see better performance for a single request, or the ability to handle more requests?  (I'm running a machine-learning task that is CPU intensive.)  Maybe that can't be answered without more specifics, but asking in case there's a general answer.
4. In the "revisions" tab, you can opt into a preview of "slower cold starts but more effective CPU usage", but it's not clear how much of a tradeoff each is... does anyone have concrete knowledge/experience with "how much slower to start vs. faster to process?"

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Tip: I would not focus on CPU utilization. Focus on response time. The graph does not indicate which is slower, just how much CPU is utilized. In most cases, that means very little.

Comment: @JohnHanley I appreciate the tip!  Indeed, I would like to minimize response time (3. and 4. above).  I have guesses that 3. more cpus = faster response and 4. more utilization with slower cold starts also = faster response.  But not sure.  Typical response time for this task is 2-5 minutes.

Comment: You have the classic problem, how do I make my program run faster. How many CPUs to use and their speed are just one side of the equation. Software design is important. Networking, latency, storage, etc are important. Using faster processors when your design is waiting for resources is pointless. Your question cannot be answered with facts or citations, only opinions and recommendations. That would require a design review of your application requirements.

Comment: @JohnHanley that's fair, and I'll certainly optimize within the app logic.  That said, without knowing whether the graph means 20% or 95%, any VM optimization is a shot in the dark.

Comment: That graph has a units in the legend.  The Google graph has "%" without indicating which is CPU and which is time.  That said, I appreciate the spirit of your comment, and I read the Google docs (linked from their own metrics page), which also omitted this info.

Comment: It's not the graph, it's the legend that is ambiguous.  While I appreciate your willingness to write, I don't think these comments are productive anymore, and make a number of inappropriate assumptions.  Thanks anyway for taking the time; this will be the end of my correspondence on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, the graph shows that your requests are using about 20% of your CPU. The legend below means that 95% of the time, your CPU usage will be around 20%.
2. Yes you can increase your concurrency up to a maximum of `1000`. You can check this documentation on [concurrency values](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency_values) and [setting maximum concurrency (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/concurrency). The default value for concurrency is `80`.
3. I haven't tried this as it would depend on the load of the request. There are instances where there are single requests with lighter or heavier load.
4. Setting your **minimum number of instances** to `1` will reduce the number of cold starts as it will be ready to serve incoming requests as it will run on idle. The downside is that this would incur charges as the service is still running. Google recommends purchasing a [committed use discount](https://cloud.google.com/run/cud) as these charges are very predictable. Full documentation regarding minimum instances can be found through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances).